# Is the unit in the definition of a symmetric Frobenius algebra necessary?

Tags: linear-algebra, qa.quantum-algebra, frobenius-algebras

Consider a symmetric Frobenius algebra without unit, that is, a finite-dimensional complex associative algebra $\delta$ with a linear functional $\epsilon$, such that $\epsilon\circ \delta$ is a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form, and
$$ \epsilon\circ\delta\circ(\delta\otimes \operatorname{id})=\epsilon\circ\delta\circ(\operatorname{id}\otimes\delta)\;.$$
Can every such algebra be equipped with a unique unit to make it a full symmetric Frobenius algebra?

Comment: Do you require the symmetric bilinear form to be non-degenerate? The 1-dimensional non-unital algebra with zero multiplication (i.e. A is generated by x and x^2=0), satisfies your conditions with any linear functional.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I forgot to say non-degenerate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote by $V$ the underlying vector space of your algebra and by $\bullet$ the product. Then the nondegenerate bilinear form $\eta$ identifies $V$ with $V^*$. I claim that the preimage of the linear form $\varepsilon$ under this identification is the unit. Denote it by 1. Then, for any $a,b \in V$, we have
$$
\eta(1 \bullet a , b) = \varepsilon(1 \bullet a \bullet b) = \eta(1, a \bullet b) = \varepsilon(a \bullet b) = \eta(a, b),
$$
where we use the definition of 1 in the third equality.

It follows that $1 \bullet a = a$.

Comment: Thanks! In the last expression of the equation the dot should be a comma, right?

Comment: Had to draw it in pictures to understand it, but yes that works, thanks! Am I correct that the symmetry requirement is necessary for the left- and right unit to be the same?

Comment: Yes, to both. I replaced the dot with a comma. For the left and right units to be the same you need the bilinear form $\eta$ to be symmetric.